# How to detect the bold or specific color fonts while fetching texts through OCR in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am trying to create one iOS app to get Questions and Answers through OCR. The concern in it is that to get the answer which is bold or with red colored. Is there any way to detect the bold, Italic, or specific colored fonts from text through OCR?

Comment: What OCR API are you using?

Comment: I have tried to use  https://www.newocr.com/api/ and  https://ocr.space/ocrapi. Is there any other APIs available which can provide this output?